# How can I monitor a rake task with monit?

Tags: rake, monit

I have a rake task that I want to run forever and ever and ever. It's job is to monitor a table and process entries in that table as they occur (from another rake task that I need to monitor also).

I am already using monit to monitor a Sidekiq worker. However, I don't know what to put in the "stop" entry in the `monitrc` file. The only way I would know how to kill a `rake` task is with the `kill` command.

How can I ensure that my two `rake` tasks are restarted if they are killed or if they die?

I found a [link](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) to a list of examples, but none of them are really even close to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great resource [here.](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2009/01/running-rake-tasks-in-background-with.html)

Comment: The link listed here is now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if using Ruby 1.9+) is to use the "Process.spawn" and "Process.daemon" method to spawn unix processes and return their PID. This will allow you to write the monit script in ruby.